# Gradle task runtimeOnlyDependenciesMetadata failed

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, gradle

I've added runtimeOnly dependency without explicitly providing a version (should be taken form BOM).

When I'm building project, the gradle task `runtimeOnlyDependenciesMetadata` fails.
Here is error I'me getting:

```
./gradlew build

Execution failed for task ':service:bootJar'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':service:runtimeOnlyDependenciesMetadata'.
   > Could not find com.lib.common:lib-jdbc-starter:.
     Required by:
         project :service

Possible solution:
 - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html
```

However, when I add version explicitly `runtimeOnly("com.lib.common:lib-jdbc-starter:1.1.0")` build succeeds. Also work fine if I change to `implementation("com.lib.common:lib-jdbc-starter")`.

Kotlin project, here is `build.gradle`

```
buildscript {

    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.3.1.RELEASE'
        springCloudVersion = 'Greenwich.SR6'
    }

    repositories {
        maven { url "https://artifactory" }
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }

}

plugins {
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm"
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.spring" version "1.3.72"
    id 'net.researchgate.release' version '2.7.0'
    id "com.github.ben-manes.versions" version "0.20.0"
    id 'com.avast.gradle.docker-compose' version "0.10.10"
}

apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: "kotlin-spring"
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'docker-compose'

repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://artifactory"
        metadataSources {
            mavenPom()
            artifact()
        }
    }
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}

configurations.all {
    exclude group: 'org.projectlombok'
}

dependencies {
        // BOM
    implementation platform("com.lib.common:bom-dependencies:2.3.0")    
    
    runtimeOnly("com.lib.common:lib-jdbc-starter")
}
```

How can I solve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've telling Gradle to use the Bill of Materials for the `implementation` configuration but adding `lib-jdbc-starter` to the `runtimeOnly` configuration.  You need to declare the platform for each configuration you want it to apply to.

You could try:

```
dependencies {
    // BOM
    runtimeOnly platform("com.lib.common:bom-dependencies:2.3.0")    
    
    runtimeOnly("com.lib.common:lib-jdbc-starter")
}
```